# Is it possible to hide content for one specific user group?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, acl

I know we can show content based on a users access level using Joomla ACL, but is it possible to show content to all users except for one specific group? If so, how?

I've tried creating an access level called `news` that includes all groups except `no_news` group then assigned my module access level of `news`.

Unfortunately users belonging to the `no_news` group were able to see the content. Any suggestions?

The `no_news` class is inherited from registered.

Answer (score 0):

Is your no_news group inherited from Public? If so, exclude Public group from NEWS access level. Basically the idea is that if the parent group has access, then all child groups will also have.

Comment: No it isn't. The no_news group is inherited from the registered group.

Comment: Then you need to exclude Registered from NEWS access level or inherit your no_news group from Public and exclude Public group from NEWS access level. I describe the concept in my answer.